# tap:AMP.setState not working intermittently

Tags: accelerated-mobile-page, google-amp

tap:AMP.setState not working at times but it works when i reload the page.

```
<div class="padTop20">
    <a [class]="model.nextStep.expand ? 'hide' : 'show'" role="button" class="show" on="tap:AMP.setState({model:{nextStep:{expand: true}}})" id="showmore">Show more</a>
    <a [class]="model.nextStep.expand ? 'show' : 'hide'" role="button" class="hide" on="tap:AMP.setState({model:{nextStep:{expand: false}}})" id="showless">Show less</a>
</div>
```

Here's my default state:

```
<amp-state id="model">
        <script type="application/json">
            {              
               "nextStep":{  
                  "expand":false
               }
            }
        </script>
    </amp-state>
```

Is it something because of network that makes it behave like this?? Appreciate for any help! thanks!

Comment: Can you please post the full example. One thing: expand is never set to `true`.

Comment: I have two links actually one to set true and other one to set false like below

Comment: I have two links actually one to set true and other one to set false like below

<div class="padTop20">
 <a [class]="model.nextStep.expand ? 'hide' : 'show'" role="button" class="show" on="tap:AMP.setState({model:{nextStep:{expand: true}}})" id="showmore">Show more</a>
 <a [class]="model.nextStep.expand ? 'show' : 'hide'" role="button" class="hide" on="tap:AMP.setState({model:{nextStep:{expand: false}}})" id="showless">Show less</a>
</div>

On page load, i get show more link. Upon selecting show more link, i expect amp state to get updated there by show less link will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You should try;

[class]="(model.nextStep.expand == 'true') ? 'hide' : 'show'"

and

[class]="(model.nextStep.expand == 'false') ? 'show' : 'hide'"

On page load, as soon as the DOM is loaded, your initial state (false) is fired and [class] is rendered because of amp-bind.

You didn't post much in terms of any console errors or validation errors you might be facing with AMP (which will affect the functionality if you did something weird/wrong)